# How to recover a closed convex set from its support function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, support-function

Let $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ closed and convex.
Its *support function* is defined as $h_A(u)=\sup_{x\in A}\langle x,u\rangle$, for every $u\in \mathbb R^n$.

Being $A$ closed, there must be, for each $u$, some $x_u\in A$ such that $h_A(u)=\langle x_u,u\rangle$.

For example, the support function of a unit circle is $h(n_\theta)=1$, with $h(n_\theta) = \langle x_\theta,n_\theta\rangle$ with $x_\theta=n_\theta$.

In $\mathbb R^2$, we can parametrise $u$ via its polar angle (sticking to vectors with unit norm). Denote such unit vectors with $n_\theta$.
Then we write $h_A(n_\theta) = \langle x_\theta,n_\theta\rangle$ for some $x_\theta\in A$ (there might be more than one choice of $x_\theta$, so let's say we use some criterion to fix one). We want to recover the points $x_\theta$ corresponding to each $\theta$, and thus $\partial A$.
Assuming $\theta\mapsto h_A(n_\theta)$ is differentiable around $\theta$, we have
$$\partial_\theta h(n_\theta) = \langle \partial_\theta x_\theta, n_\theta\rangle + \langle x_\theta,\hat\theta\rangle,$$
where $\partial_\theta n_\theta=\hat\theta$ is the unit versor orthogonal to $n_\theta$.

If $\langle \partial_\theta  x_\theta,n_\theta\rangle=0$, one can easily recover $x_\theta$, whose polar coordinates are $h(n_\theta)$ and $\partial_\theta h(n_\theta)$. This is the case whenever $\partial_\theta x_\theta=0$ (as happens for example for polygons), or when $\partial_\theta x_\theta$ is orthogonal to $n_\theta$ (this is the case *e.g.* for the case of the unit circle, in which $x_\theta=n_\theta$).

Does $\partial_\theta h_A(n_\theta)$ return the polar coordinate of $x_\theta$ also in the general case? In other words, does $\langle \partial_\theta x_\theta,n_\theta\rangle=0$ always hold?
And what about the case of higher dimensions? Does this technique generalise straightforwardly to $\mathbb R^n$?

---

I asked a closely related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3449226/173147), and used the same technique discussed here in an answer. This question differs from that one in that it uses a different language/formalism, and focuses on the validity of a specific relation (whether $\partial_\theta x_\theta$ is orthogonal to $n_\theta$) to show that the derivatives of the support function return the coordinates of the corresponding point in its support hyperplane.

Another way to derive the convex region corresponding to a given support function is mentioned in [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2114145/173147), but the focus is there on using the convex conjugate (which as far as I understand is not as directly applicable in practice as the method discussed here).

Comment: What do you mean by 'recover'? Surely $A= \{ x | \langle v, x \rangle \le h_A(v) \text{ for all } v \}$?

Comment: @copper.hat sure, but how would you use that to actually be able to derive/draw numerically the (boundary of the) set $A$? Using the system with the derivatives of the support function we can actually recover $x_\theta$ from the knowledge of $h_A$. I mean, in the example of a circle, given $h_A(u)=1$ realise that $A$ is the unit disk (and be able to do the same in less trivial cases).

Comment: Very minor point, just being closed is not enough to ensure the existence of $x_u$. This is an interesting question, but I can't imagine a straightforward answer unless there are additional constraints.

Comment: @copper.hat interesting. What would be a counterexample in which $x_u$ does not exist for some $u$? Would assuming compactness ensure the existence of $x_u$? I mean thinking geometrically (probably naively) I struggle to see how $x_u$ could not exist for some direction $u$ for which $h_A(u)$ is finite. By the way, I actually kind of assumed that this method was a standard one to reconstruct a set from its support function. Are you saying it isn't?

Comment: If $h_A$ is finite in every direction then $A$ is weakly bounded and hence strongly bounded hence compact, so you would need $h_A$ to be unbounded in some direction and for such directions, no corresponding $x_u$ can exist.

Comment: I am not sure it there is a general method to 'reconstruct' $A$ from its support function (other than the obvious in the first comment). Perhaps in 2d/3d some stuff exists (I am thinking computer graphics), but in general, I am not aware of anything.

Comment: I guess you may start with $x\in\partial A$ iff $\forall\theta\colon\langle x,n_{\theta}\rangle-h(n_{\theta})\le 0$ and $\exists\theta\colon\langle x,n_{\theta}\rangle-h(n_{\theta})=0$. Then maximum of the LHS is $0$, and gradient is zero necessarily. (Assuming convex body, smoothness etc)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming some smoothness, for example, that the convex body  has a strictly convex boundary and that every boundary point has a unique normal, then it follows that the support function is differentiable, and its gradient evaluated at a unit vector $u$ is equal to the unique boundary point of the convex body it supports, where $u$ is a normal vector. Therefore the gradient map provides an effective parametrization of the boundary via the unit Euclidean sphere , and you can use it to actually draw the boundary in two and three dimensions, if you have an explicit expression for the support function.

By a convex body I mean a convex, compact with non-empty interior subset.

Comment: thanks. This makes sense, but I guess I was asking for a way to prove this (which in the 2D case, I think would amount to showing that $\partial_\theta x_\theta\perp n_\theta$). Can you point me to a reference?

Comment: This is classic. It appears in the Bonnesen-Fenchel book "Theory of convex bodies", and presented nicely in Schneider's more recent "Convex Bodies - theory of Bruni-Minkowski".